# Offline Maps API usage

Tags: android, google-maps, offline

I'm doing a hiking App and since I need to track paths in very remote places I need to use the maps offline. If the user downloads a map using the offline feature from the Google Maps App, and then from my App I use the location tracker API, will those coordinates be available for the location tracker API, or It's always gonna try to use the network connection, even if the Google Maps App downloaded the map before hand?

I know that the Google Maps API doesn't have any way to download or cache the maps, so my only choices here are doing something like this or turning to OpenStreetMap that has offline support.

Answer (score 0):

Maps API in offline mode is not offered by Google. The API requires an Internet connection to download the geospatial data it needs to display the map. This data can't be saved or served offline.